# Opencart Display Total Product Count in List of Children Categories

Tags: opencart

I am using opencart 1.5.4.

I would like to show a count of how many products are in a child category on my list of categories on this page:

```
http://50.87.186.42/index.php?route=product/category&path=59_60
```

I have tried to add the code but it looks like it is already in the controller (category/controller/module/category.php)

Here is the code I am looking at:

```
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $data = array(
                'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                'filter_sub_category' => true
            );

            $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data);

            $total += $product_total;

            $children_data[] = array(
                'category_id' => $child['category_id'],
                'name'        => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $product_total . ')' : ''),
                'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id']) 
            );      
        }
```

It looks like it is using either $total or $product_total but it isn't displaying on the front end. Did I turn this off somewhere or is there a way to turn it back on?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

repalce this foreach (not $children the whole $categories) and let me know if its work or not ...

```
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts(array('filter_category_id' => $category['category_id']));

        $children_data = array();

        $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

        foreach ($children as $child) {



            $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts(array('filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id']));

            $total += $product_total;

            $children_data[] = array(
                'category_id' => $child['category_id'],
                'name'        => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $product_total . ')' : ''),
                'total'    => $product_total,
                'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id']) 
            );      
        }

        $this->data['categories'][] = array(
            'category_id' => $category['category_id'],
            'name'        => $category['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $total . ')' : ''),
            'children'    => $children_data,
            'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
        );  
    }
```